# Javascript error - Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suddenly my js files are not loading. 
Below are the errors i am getting.

```
main.js:70 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).actual is not a function
    at centerHomeBannerText (main.js:70)
    at main.js:74
centerHomeBannerText @ main.js:70
(anonymous) @ main.js:74

jquery.validate.min.js:4 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

owl.carousel.js:394 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ===
```

Below are the code.
You can see how i am loading js files.

```
<script src="./js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/index.js"></script>      
<script src="./js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="./js/bootbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.mywebsitename.com/libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/wow.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.isonscreen.js"></script>
<script src="./js/script.js"></script>
<script src="./js/main.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

When i inspect `Jquery.validate` in chrome. It is showing below.

```
oy:funct�Q��Q��i���XR�R��R�lTo-blur").off(".validate-equalTo"
```

Comment: show us the javascript code where this error occurs ?

Comment: Move `main.js` to the end?

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: why there is a single '.' src="./js/main.js"> in src what it is means ?

Answer (score 0):

it may b the sequence issue just move your jquery scripts at topmost

```
<script src="./js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>    
<script src="./js/moment.min.js"></script>
```

```
<script src="./js/bootbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.mywebsitename.com/libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/wow.min.js"></script>

<script src="./js/jquery.isonscreen.js"></script>
<script src="./js/script.js"></script>

<script src="./js/main.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether I am right or wrong.  let me post my opinion.

I think .actual() is third party plugin, not a jQuery function and I dont see .actual() has been imported in your script list.

Also, You have to move the jquery migrate plugin after jQuery script.

Please correct me if I am wrong.